# WSO2 ESB - Error parsing JSON when using the clone mediator with a REST endpoint

Tags: json, rest, wso2, wso2-esb

I have two REST services that return some simple JSON. I'm using the clone mediator to call each service and then return the aggregated message to the client.

The problem is that everytime I call the API, I get the following error on the ESB output:

`ERROR - OMSourcedElementImpl Could not get parser from data source for element jsonObject`

I've tested the same REST service individually, without the clone mediator, and it works without a problem.

Here is the API sequence:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="PolicyQuery" context="/policy/query">
   <resource methods="POST">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="ROOT" scope="default">
            <root:rootelement xmlns:root="www.wso2esb.com"/>
         </property>
         <log level="full"/>
         <clone continueParent="true" id="test" sequential="true">
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <send>
                     <endpoint>
                        <address uri="http://ip.jsontest.com/" format="rest"/>
                     </endpoint>
                  </send>
               </sequence>
            </target>
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <send>
                     <endpoint>
                        <address uri="http://ip.jsontest.com/" format="rest"/>
                     </endpoint>
                  </send>
               </sequence>
            </target>
         </clone>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <aggregate>
            <completeCondition>
               <messageCount min="-1" max="-1"/>
            </completeCondition>
            <onComplete expression="//return" enclosingElementProperty="ROOT">
               <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
               <send/>
            </onComplete>
         </aggregate>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Am I doing anything wrong? I'm using WSO2 5.0.0 (I've also tested with 4.9.0 and I get the same problem).

The request payload I'm sending is:

```
{ 
    IdNumber : "8008185315088", 
    LastName : null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked fine for me after updating out sequence like this. Can you try this?

```
  <outSequence>
     <log level="full"/>
     <aggregate>
        <completeCondition>
           <messageCount min="2" max="2"/>
        </completeCondition>
        <onComplete expression="//ip" enclosingElementProperty="ROOT">
           <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
           <send/>
        </onComplete>
     </aggregate>
  </outSequence>
```

Note: The error you're getting can occur if the json you get is in a wrong format. But with this sample, I don't see such an issue.

**Edit**:

Problem is with json format. It should be fixed like this.

```
{ 
    "IdNumber" : "8008185315088", 
    "LastName" : null
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error: `[2016-08-23 13:49:56,240]  INFO - LogMediator To: /policy/query, MessageID: urn:uuid:e8019694-2c25-4b29-b9ea-a8ae9d4af41e, Direction: request, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error obtaining parser from data source:null, Payload: {
 IdNumber : '8008185218088',
 LastName : null
}`

Comment: How sure are you this problem is caused by the outSequence? Even if I modify the outSequence to only log, I still get the problem... `      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
      </outSequence>`

Comment: Also, now that I think of it, does it have anything to the json that i POST to the api, which gets forwarded to the endpoints? See the payload info in my previous comment.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, that error can happen if the json is incorrectly formatted. It's not specific to out sequence. 
And your json is wrong. It should be
`{ "IdNumber" : "8008185218088", "LastName" : null }`

Comment: You're right - my json fields weren't encased in quotes - and now it works. Very interesting! For the purposes of my answer, I'll add my POST json data, if you can update your answer to indicate an incorrectly formatted payload, and I'll choose it as the answer. Thanks for your help, really appreciate it.